# jquery get id value from dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val1">
<div id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val2">
<div id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val3">
```

Onclick event in jquery need to get value of the div. Exact number of divs created is dynamic

Comment: If you click on the `div`, the `id` will always be accessible as `this.id`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use input instead of div:

Try this:

Html :

```
<input type="text" id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val1"/>
<input type="text" id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val2"/>
<input type="text" id="tag<%=count++%>" value="val3"/>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('input[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
    alert(this.value);
 });
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/20/)

**using div:**

try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
 });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/22/)

Comment: @user3035379: If you have got solution of your question you should accept an answer:)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, value is not an attribute of div.

But still you can use this:

```
var value = $('div').attr('value')
```

to get the ID attribute, and using that, you can get the value as:

```
$('#' + value).attr('id');
```

You can use it as a variable and then do what so ever!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the '[Attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)' selector and then use `this.id`:

```
$('div[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() {  
    alert(this.id); // Get the ID
    alert($(this).attr('value')); // Get the value attribute
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q235n/1/)

You should however note that `value` isn't a valid attribute for `<div>` elements. As such, it might be better to use `data-value`, or use `<input>` instead.